Load .csv in a list with lapply while using a looping variable
I have a list (myList) of lists (A, B, C, D), each one with other lists (a1, a2, a3), which looks like this.
scenarios <- LETTERS[1:4]
patterns <- c("a1", "a2", "a3")
myList <- list()
for(i in seq_along(scenarios)){
  myList[[i]] <- list()
  for(j in seq_along(patterns)){
    myList[[i]][[j]] <- list()
  }  
  names(myList[[i]]) <- patterns  
}

names(myList) <- scenarios
myList

$A
$A$a1
list()

$A$a2
list()

$A$a3
list()

$B
$B$a1
list()

$B$a2
list()

$B$a3
list()

$C
$C$a1
list()

$C$a2
list()

$C$a3
list()

$D
$D$a1
list()

$D$a2
list()

$D$a3
list()

The files I need to upload have a path name that looks like this: ./path/A/a1_A_table.csv
I am not sure how to loop through the files name assigning the components to a variable and then storing the output in the list, in the corresponding position. So far this is my attempt.
myDfList <- list()
myDfList <- lapply(scenarios, function(scen){
  i = 1  
  myDfList[scen] <- lapply(patterns, function(df){   
    p <- patterns[i]    
    read.csv(paste0("./path/", scen, "/", p, "_", scen, "_table.csv"), sep = ",", h = T, fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")    
    i = i + 1    
  })})

I am a bit lost because I don't understand how to loop iteratively using lapply (if possible and if it makes sense), or if I just use a for loop.
EDIT: found a simpler solution than I thought.
for(scen in scenarios){
  
  for(p in patterns){
    
    # create file name
    file <- paste0("./path/", scen, "/", p, "_", scen, "_table.csv")
    
    # load data
    df <- read.csv(file, sep = ",", h = T, fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
    
    # upload data to list
    myList[[scen]][[p]] <- df 
    
  }
}


The question says I have a list myList so you would have to generate scenarios and patterns from that to be a solution to the question as stated and also add the additional condition that the patterns are the same for every scenario which is the case for the example but is not actually stated.

If you want to keep the same shape, you can use a pair of Maps.
Map(function(top, topname) {
  Map(function(mid, midname) {
    path <- paste0(".path/", topname,"/", midname,"_",topname, "_table.csv", sep=".")
    path
    # read.csv(path)
  }, top, names(top))}, 
myList, names(myList))

Since I don't have the data, this just returns the paths, but you can do whatever you want with the path in the inner Map. This returns
$A
$A$a1
[1] ".path/A/a1_A_table.csv."

$A$a2
[1] ".path/A/a2_A_table.csv."

$A$a3
[1] ".path/A/a3_A_table.csv."


$B
$B$a1
[1] ".path/B/a1_B_table.csv."

$B$a2
[1] ".path/B/a2_B_table.csv."

$B$a3
[1] ".path/B/a3_B_table.csv."


$C
$C$a1
[1] ".path/C/a1_C_table.csv."

$C$a2
[1] ".path/C/a2_C_table.csv."

$C$a3
[1] ".path/C/a3_C_table.csv."


$D
$D$a1
[1] ".path/D/a1_D_table.csv."

$D$a2
[1] ".path/D/a2_D_table.csv."

$D$a3
[1] ".path/D/a3_D_table.csv."


There is a question of whether you really need myList at all.  This gets all files with names of the desired form creating a named nested list of them without reference to it.
library(magrittr)

L <- "./path/*/*_*_table.csv" %>%
  Sys.glob %>%
  split(., basename(dirname(.))) %>%
  lapply(\(x) setNames(lapply(x, read.csv), sub("_.*", "", basename(x))))

If you do need to use myList as the starting point then traverse it with rrapply
library(rrapply)

L <- rrapply(myList, 
  classes = "list",
  cond = \(x) length(x) == 0,
  f = \(x, .xparents) sprintf("./path/%s/%s_%s_table.csv", 
    .xparents[1], .xparents[2], .xparents[1]) |>
    read.csv(),
  how = "replace")


You could also do:

fn <- function(x,y){
  nms <- names(x)
  as.list(setNames(sprintf('/path/%s/%s_%s_table.csv', y, nms, y), nms))
}

purrr::imap(myList, fn)

$A
$A$a1
[1] "/path/A/a1_A_table.csv"

$A$a2
[1] "/path/A/a2_A_table.csv"

$A$a3
[1] "/path/A/a3_A_table.csv"


$B
$B$a1
[1] "/path/B/a1_B_table.csv"

$B$a2
[1] "/path/B/a2_B_table.csv"

$B$a3
[1] "/path/B/a3_B_table.csv"


$C
$C$a1
[1] "/path/C/a1_C_table.csv"

$C$a2
[1] "/path/C/a2_C_table.csv"

$C$a3
[1] "/path/C/a3_C_table.csv"


$D
$D$a1
[1] "/path/D/a1_D_table.csv"

$D$a2
[1] "/path/D/a2_D_table.csv"

$D$a3
[1] "/path/D/a3_D_table.csv"

